# "Name: value" widget via GTK

Tags: c++, gtk, gtk3, gtkmm, gtkmm3

How to make a [widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klu7o.png) via GTK that looks like the following?

```
------------------
| Text1:    | 1  |
|-----------+----|
| Text2:    | 10 |
|-----------+----|
|           |    |
|           |    |
|           |    |
------------------
```

'Text1', 'Text2' - constant strings; '1', '10' - dynamically changed values.

What Gtk::Widget's should I use for that?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Like reading the docs. Refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) where the first step is to *search and then research*.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I'm tried to use Gtk::Label, but there was troubles with vertical offet (red line). I'm not asking how to write this. I have no ideas what Gtk elements to use.

Comment: This is just a wild guess, but it looks like you want your data arranged in a grid. Are there any widgets that might give you a grid layout? Perhaps something with a wacky name like "GtkGrid"?

Comment: @min You can first create a container. Then place 2 rows inside of it. Then each of the row will have 2 columns. And each column will have a `Gtk::Label`. This means the first column of the first row will contain a `Gtk::Label` for `"Text1"` and the second column for the first row will contain a `Gtk::Label` for `"10"`. Similarly, do the same for second row.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make Gtk::Grid with labels, align them, set column spacing and column homogeneous.

```
#include <gtkmm.h>

class window : public Gtk::Window {
protected:
    Gtk::Box box;
    Gtk::Grid grid;
    Gtk::Button button;
    Gtk::Label name1, name2, value1, value2;
    int n_click = 0;

public:
    window();
    ~window() = default;

    void on_click() {
        value1.set_label("1");
        value2.set_label(n_click % 2 ? "1" : "10");
        n_click++;
        queue_draw();
    }
};

window::window() : button("Update"),
        name1("Text:"),
        name2("Text2:")
{
    add(box);

    box.pack_start(button);
    button.signal_clicked().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &window::on_click));

    box.pack_end(grid, Gtk::PACK_SHRINK);
    grid.attach(name1,  0, 0, 2, 1);
    grid.attach(value1, 2, 0, 1, 1);
    grid.attach(name2,  0, 1, 2, 1);
    grid.attach(value2, 2, 1, 1, 1);

    name1.set_halign(Gtk::ALIGN_START);
    name2.set_halign(Gtk::ALIGN_START);
    value1.set_halign(Gtk::ALIGN_START);
    value2.set_halign(Gtk::ALIGN_START);
    grid.set_column_spacing(10);
    grid.set_column_homogeneous(true);

    show_all();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "");

    window win;
    return app->run(win);
}
```